# Is it legal to work as a student assistant in Germany if Im an Italian student?

Tags: european-union, workplace, work-permit

So I have a long residency in Italy and I'm finishing my masters, but I found a good thesis in Germany and they offered me while doing the thesis to work as a student assistant (to be able to cover my fees there)

Is this legal to me? The HR department is not being clear or helpful much.

Comment: Does the *HR department* know which citizenship you have? If not, then that will probably be the reason why their answer 'is not being clear or helpful'.

Comment: It isn't an immigration issue. There may be Germany specific paperwork that needs to be completed.

Comment: @ohwilleke If the OP is not an EU Citizen, then probably [§16c - Mobility of students (AufenthG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0294) applies. So it would be an immigration issue.

Comment: Is “Italian student” an Italian citizen, an EU citizen studying in Italy, or a non-EU citizen studying in Italy?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I was presuming that Italian was the nationality of the person in question, but I can see from your comment how Italian could modify the place where the person was currently a student rather than the nationality of the student.

Comment: @gnasher729 With a 'long residency' and tag:work-permit, I would assume a 'non-EU citizen studying in Italy'. That is what the OP should clarify. Any answer would depend in the result.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has been also asked at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24395/is-it-legal-to-work-as-a-student-assistant-in-germany-if-im-a-student-in-italy

Comment: a possible duplicate on another stack is not  a good reason to close a question on topic here

Comment: @DavidSiegel It was the OP choice to ask the question elsewhere and where they are reacting to the requests to supply the information required to answer the question properly.

Comment: I'll support the VtC on this pending an answer to @gnasher729's comment, but once that's resolved, I'm not sure why this can't be answered.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @MarkJohnson , yes im a non eu with a yearly renewed italian student visa